# How to remove directory with all of its contents?

Tags: directory, delete

I tried to remove a directory by using command `rmdir` but I got this answer:

```
The directory is not empty.
```

How to deal with such problems?

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to empty the directory first, you can use

```
rm -r
```

to recursively remove directories and their content.

Please note also that this is [already explained in the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#File_.26_Directory_Commands).

> `rmdir`: The `rmdir` command will delete an **empty** directory. To delete a directory and all of its contents recursively, use `rm -r` instead.

Since you are not an expert, I suggest that you read *carefully* that documentation page before using more the terminal, before you do some damage to your files!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove an entire directory with everything in it, you can use `rm -r` like dadexix said
and if you really want to make sure add the f for force

```
rm -rf
```

i Always do that and it Always works

Comment: Please be careful: not using -rf habitually has saved me several times from doing something disastrous.